# spark.cores.max but per node?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I'm using a autoscaling cluster from Azure Databricks.  The pyspark job has to call an external process, so I'm hoping I can leave some percentage of each node "unused" by spark.  I have found spark.cores.max, but this is the total number of cores, not the total per node.  Is there an equivalent argument that I can use to set the maximum number of cores per node?

Answer (score 0):

You can add in worker's `conf/spark-env.sh` this line:

```
SPARK_WORKER_CORES=4
```

From https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html#cluster-launch-scripts:

> SPARK_WORKER_CORES    Total number of cores to allow Spark applications to use on the machine (default: all available cores).

Comment: Do you know which option this sets?

Comment: @rsmith54 I think that it is a variable used by the bash script that starts the worker (`sbin/start-slave.sh`) and not a configuration like `spark.app.name` which can be seen from inside the application, if that is what you mean.